# Gummi via pkgsrc on mac?

Tags: package-management

On the TeX editor Gummi's Github page https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi/wiki/Installing-Gummi#install-for-your-platform, there is a link to pkgsource to get the package for macOS.

But when I run `sudo pkgin install gummi` I get `gummi is not available in the repository`.

**What is the proper way to install it?**

Comment: This might be better asked on https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi/issues. But from looking at other macOS-related issues, macOS supports doesn't seem to be the top priority.

Comment: Looking at the pkgsrc page for gummi I suspect that there is not a prebuilt version for macos so pkgin. You might need to build from source.